# ¿Cómo configurar el servidor Nginx en Red Hat y encontrar el archivo adecuado para su configuración?

Tags: docker, nginx, red-hat

Actualmente, estoy usando en Dockerfile en mi aplicación de angular, la configuración para usar Nginx de Red Hat que es la siguiente:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/nginx-120
//en la carpeta dist/angular123 estan los archivo depués de hacer npm build --prod en angular
ADD --chown=1001:0 dist/angular123  /tmp/src

##no estoy seguro de como se estable la configuración
ADD --chown=1001:0 nginx-cfg /tmp/src

RUN /usr/libexec/s2i/assemble


CMD /usr/libexec/s2i/run
```

No sé si me está tomando correctamente la configuración en mi aplicación, ya que cuando le doy a la ruta otra dirección me sale un error
404 Not Found,
normalmente no me debe salir este error cuando esta configurado bien

esta es la configuración de mi servidor Nginx Red Hat

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost2;
    root         /opt/app-root/src;
    index        index.html;
}
```

dejo repositorio red hat Nginx 1.20

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://github.com/sclorg/nginx-container/blob/master/1.20/README.md)

si me pueden echar una ayuda se lo agradecería

otra cosa me hice el mismo ejemplo, de una imagen que no es de red hat y funciona perfectamente
les dejo el ejemplo

```
FROM nginx:1.24-alpine

COPY dist/angular123 /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 8080
```

Ando un poco confundido la configuración de red hat, una ayuda me vendría muy bien